# WAMP refuses mobile connection to localhost

Tags: localhost, wamp

WAMP 3.2.0 site working fine on Desktop PC but external devices unable to connect to the localhost.

httpd-vhosts- :

```
# Virtual Hosts
  <VirtualHost *:7246>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
      Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide more detail please - is this the server config file?

Comment: @Mikkel Thank you. There is another config file in WAMP for server configuration (httpd) but from what I have looked at already version 3.2.0 uses this separate httpd-vhosts- file which I believe is the config file for setting up hosting and it's accessibility.